# How to declare and use a method that accepts as its parameter a base class and it's children classes

Tags: c#

I was wondering how in C# could I declare and use a method that can take in as an argument a base class as well as any children classes derived from the base class?

thank you

Comment: When you pass a parameter to a method, you can specify any type that is a subtype of that in the method signature.  This is part of the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put type of base class as parameter but this is asking for trouble. If you going to access base class memebers you need to really understand what you do.

This type of task usually handled using interfaces.